# How to handle live data and view state in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, model

I'm using AngularJS for some time now, and it does the job fine. However lately i have some thinking problems with data sets.

Lets say i have an array of items:

```
[
 { id: 1, votes: 10, detailInformation: 'Interesting #1' },
 { id: 2, votes: 12, detailInformation: 'Interesting #2' }
]
```

I set an $timer to retrieve this information every 60 seconds form an REST webservice to give the user the most up to date information.

These items are showed in a following format to the user:

```
|   ID: {{item.id}}    Votes: {{item.votes}}                                             |
|   <span data-ng-click="item.showInfo = true">Click here to view detail info</span>     |
|   <span data-ng-show="item.showInfo == true">{{item.detailInformation}}</span>         |
```

This example works fine, but when the timer retrieves the new content it throws away the view state (item.showInfo = true). What is (or are) the best practice for these kind of situations? How can i seperate this client-only state from the server information that needs to be up to date?

Comment: what do you mean by throws away the view state? does it set it to false?

Comment: It replaces the obj array containing [{id:1, votes:10, detailInformation: '', showInfo: true} ..] with the obj array from the server not containing showInfo: true (the client side state for expanding an detail view). The the array for example becomes [{ id: 1, votes: 3748, detailInformation: 'Interesting #1' }...]

Comment: ok so you included showInfo in the array from the response to server. If you want to contain it then have it outside the array. a different scope object I meant

Comment: Could you write this pattern as an awnser so that i can close this issue? I understand the idea now ;)

Comment: sure will do that in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to V31 for giving me the idea, but i worked it out a bit more generic:

```
// In your controller
$scope.items = [] // Contains the webservice data
$scope.itemsViewState = {} // Map that will contain all the viewstate with the ID as key.
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    ID: {{item.id}} <br />
    Votes: {{item.votes}} <br />
    <span data-ng-click="itemsViewState[item.id] = true">Click here to view detail info</span> 
    <span data-ng-show="itemsViewState[item.id] == true">{{item.detailInformation}}</span>
</div>
```

---

In case you need to save multiple properties per object remember to create an Map for level you go deeper:

```
// In your controller
$scope.items = [] // Contains the webservice data
$scope.itemsViewState = {} // Map that will contain all the viewstate with the ID as key.
$scope.openDetail = function($item) { 
$scope.itemsViewState[item.id] = {}; 
$scope.itemsViewState[item.id]['subprop'] = true; }
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    ID: {{item.id}} <br />
    Votes: {{item.votes}} <br />
    <span data-ng-click="openDetail(item)">Click here to view detail info</span> 
    <span data-ng-show="itemsViewState[item.id]['subprop'] == true">{{item.detailInformation}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you need to add the showInfo as a separate object and not include in your response object that comes from the server so something like this in your controller:

```
app.controller('test', ['$scope','urService',function($scope,urService){
    $scope.showInfo = true;
    urService.getData(function(data){
       //update data in the another scope object
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store `item.showInfo` on different reference:

JS:

```
$http.get('/api/endpoint').then(function (data) {
  $scope.items = data;
  $scope.isShown = new Array(data.length); // set $scope.isShown at the first time receive data;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <button ng-click="isShown[$index] = true">Click here to view detail info</button>
  <span ng-show="isShown.[$index]">{{ item.detailInformation }}</span>
</div>
```